# Strange Routing error in rails 3. Rails changes the route that is specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a rails 3 app, and when I click the link to my terms page, it routes to a completely different controller, than what the routes should use. Stranger still, the route works when I'm not logged in, and I'm using devise.

I get this error when clicking the link when I'm logged in.

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}

<%= link_to "Terms", terms_path %>
```

Routes (in the order they appear in routes.rb):

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}

resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
    post :accept
  end
end

match '/terms',     to: 'static_pages#user_agreement'
```

Static Pages Controller

```
def user_agreement

end
```

Rake Routes

```
terms        /terms(.:format)                     static_pages#user_agreement
```

This also happens for every other action that I've routed this way to the staticpages controller, but not for any other actions that route to different controller.

Update: Terms Page
Header:

```
<%= link_to "Follow", users_path %>
<%= link_to current_user.name, current_user %>
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Footer:

```
<%= link_to "Welcome", welcome_path %>
<%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(@user) %>
<%= link_to "Terms", terms_path %>
```

All the content is pure html.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's actually *on* the page you're linking to? Do you have links to something else, like in your navigation/header/footer/etc, like a user edit page?

Comment: It just plain text. Along with the same headers and footers that every page has.

Comment: You have no `link_to` or user paths in your user agreement page, navigation, header, footer, application layout, or an included partial?

Comment: I've updated it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a link to `edit_user_path` with no `@user` as hinted in the comments.

You should almost certainly be using `current_user` anyway.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! It makes perfect sense now that I know whats going on, but I don't think I would have ever gotten to it on my own.